# Pass a partition filter from outer query to inner

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a query that joins data from 3 tables, `table1 INNER JOIN table2 LEFT JOIN table3` .
All 3 tables MUST have a partition filter applied during query. Currently the filter is set to
`WHERE _PARTITIONDATE IS NOT NULL` . I want to save the inner query as a view, so that my end users can supply the partition date and the inner query only reads the partitions that the user requests data from. Is there a way to pass the partition date to the view definition ? For example: I want 2021-12-31 to be passed to the WHERE conditions on the WITH clauses, instead of `WHERE _PARTITIONDATE IS NOT NULL`

```
SELECT * FROM (
            WITH T1 AS (
                      SELECT column1, column2, _PARTITIONDATE
                      FROM `projectid.datasetid.table1`
                      WHERE _PARTITIONDATE IS NOT NULL
                  )
             ,T2 AS  (

                      SELECT column3, column4, _PARTITIONDATE
                      FROM `projectid.datasetid.table2` 
                      WHERE _PARTITIONDATE IS NOT NULL
                  )
             ,T3 AS (
                      SELECT column5, column6,_PARTITIONDATE
                      FROM `projectid.datasetid.table3` 
                      WHERE _PARTITIONDATE IS NOT NULL
                  )

                  SELECT 
                         T1.column1,
                         T1.column2,
                         T2.column3,
                         T2.column4,
                         T3.column5,
                         T3.column6,
                         T1._PARTITIONDATE AS PARTITIONDATE
                  FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
                                        ON T1.column1 = T2.column3 
                                           T1._PARTITIONDATE = T2._PARTITIONDATE
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN T3
                                        ON T3.column5 = T2.column3 AND
                                           T3._PARTITIONDATE = T2._PARTITIONDATE  
                                           
)  WHERE PARTITIONDATE = '2021-12-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called push predicate, in [oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_push_pred.htm) it is a hint /*+ push_pred */ in big query it is done automatically so you just need to create view without filter. Please refer the [article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql?hl=sv#standard_sql_highlights)

Advantages of standard SQL
Standard SQL complies with the SQL 2011 standard, and has extensions that support querying nested and repeated data. It has several advantages over legacy SQL, including:

- Composability using WITH clauses and SQL functions
- Subqueries in the SELECT list and WHERE clause Correlated subqueries
- ARRAY and STRUCT data types Inserts, updates, and deletes
- COUNT(DISTINCT ) is exact and scalable, providing the accuracy
- of EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT without its limitations Automatic predicate
- **push-down through JOINs Complex JOIN predicates, including arbitrary
  expressions**

Additionally you may try [parametrized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) :

```
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--parameter=corpus::romeoandjuliet \
--parameter=min_word_count:INT64:250 \
'SELECT
  word, word_count
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
WHERE
  corpus = @corpus
AND
  word_count >= @min_word_count
ORDER BY
  word_count DESC'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The predicate push-down will pass '2021-12-31' to only T1, since PARTITIONDATE alias is defined on T1. The other two tables also require a partition filter. Is there a way to pass the same filter to all 3 tables. I don't want to ask my users to do a WHERE PARTITIONDATE1 = '2021-12-31' AND PARTITIONDATE2 = '2021-12-31' AND PARTITIONDATE3 = '2021-12-31' since it is not conventional and might confuse users.

Comment: 1 ) I suggest that to move this requirement to some Analytic tool  (Looker, Data Studio) where you can use parameters for query and query will be optimal
2) you can add in where conditions inside your inner query like T1._PARTITIONDATE = T2._PARTITIONDATE and T2._PARTITIONDATE = T3._PARTITIONDATE but cost of execution may be huge and time as well